# How to convert the cucumber Data table in the Examples section to Map<Key,Value> using java

Tags: java, datatable, cucumber

I am interested in getting feedback on converting a data table in the examples section into a map

```
Feature: Data Table Reader

Scenario Outline: User Login scenario

Given User is at the login page of the application

When User login with the following <username> and <password> with data in excel

Examples:
         | username | password |
         | value_1  | value_1  |
         | value_2  | value_2  |
         | value_3  | value_3  |
```

We have to convert the above Data table in the Example to Map.
Map should be stored as , , ,, < password: value_2>, < password: value_3>

Answer (score 2):

How are you getting hold of the examples data? Isn't each row from examples just passed into the step?

If you have a step with a data table

```
Given the following usernames and passwords
     | username | password |
     | value_1  | value_1  |
     | value_2  | value_2  |
     | value_3  | value_3  |
```

You can access the table directly as a List of Maps. Each item in the list represents one row of the data table which is provided as a map where the keys are the column headings and the values are the values from the data table.

```
    @Given("^the following usernames and passwords$")
    public void the_following_usernames_and_passwords(List<Map<String, String>> dataTable) {
    for (Map<String, String> dataRow : dataTable) {
        String username = dataRow.get("username");
        String password = dataRow.get("password");
        // ... do something ... 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, I need to fetch data from Examples: section but
not from the step. My requirement is to fetch all headers and rows available in the Examples: section upfront and store it into map. cucumber doesn't support this functionality. I am hoping that we can have to manipulate cucumber source code. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Maybe you can just use the gherkin parser? I've not tried, but there's a GherkinTest.java test in https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin-java that might point you in the right direction? It looks like if you can get the gerkhin document you can drill down to the examples. I've not tried it though. messages.get(0).getGherkinDocument().getFeature().getChildren(0).getScenario().getExamples(0);

Comment: Why are you using examples here? Why do you need more than one user to prove that a user can login? You can simplify your cuking by avoiding example tables, you don't need them.